# Show that the center of a group of order 60 cannot have order 4?

Tags: sylow-theory

This seems to be related to Sylow's theorems, but I have no idea how?

Comment: See [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160716002753AApV3qA).

Answer (score 7):

Assume that $|Z(G)|=4$. $Z(G)$ is normal, so the group $G/Z(G)$ has order 15.
But [every group of order 15 is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208760/simple-method-the-show-that-a-group-of-order-15-is-cyclic?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [that means that $G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian) - contradiction. (Because if $G$ is abelian, then $G=Z(G)$)

Comment: Another point for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point.

Comment: How is saying that "G is abelian" a contradiction?  Are all groups of order 60 abelian?

Comment: No: if the quotient of a group by its center is *cyclic*, the group is abelian. Now $G$ abelian implies $Z(G)=G$, hence $Z(G)$ does not have order $4$.

Comment: user247327: I edited