# Show that every group of order 30 have an element of order 15

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that every group of order 30 has an order of 15, without using Sylow's theorems. My attempt is to use the Cauchy theorem and from there I obtain that there are elements with order 2, 3 and 5.
But I don't know how to conclude that there is an element of order 15.

Comment: It is enough to prove that there is a subgroup of order $15$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208760/simple-method-the-show-that-a-group-of-order-15-is-cyclic.

Comment: Thanks for the help!